# Styling NavBar with active link

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

How can I have a `Navbar` which active items get highlighted?

I tried some samples, however I could not change the Active style to get desired lookup.
Here is my `_Layout.cshtml` file:

```
@{
    ViewBag.AppName = "My Application!";
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title @ViewBag.AppName</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid rtl" >
            <div class="navbar-header" style="float:right">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink((string)ViewBag.AppName, "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            @*<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</a></li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>*@
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Summary", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Request1", "Index", "PaymentRequest")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Request2", "Index", "CaptialPaymentRequest")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Request3", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Request4", "Index", "Contract")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Request5", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

If you notice I have below line for test:

```
        <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Summary", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

Which Highlights the Summary link however, I want that:

1- MVC automatically make link of current page active

2- Style of Active link changes (I used below css in my Site.css which is not working)

```
.navbar #nav > .active > a {
    color: red;
}
```

Here is my NavBar looks like:
[image]

Comment: I think `.navbar #nav > .active > a { 
    color: red;
}` should be `.navbar #navbar > .active > a {
    color: red;
}`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao it did not helped

Comment: You do not have any elements with `id="nav"` (so `#nav` selects nothing). Just use `.active > a { color: red; }`. And are you wanting to set the `class="active"` based on the link to clicked - i.e.. if you navigate to `../CaptialPaymentRequest/Index` by clicking on 'Request2' then you want 'Request2' to be highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

Add an id="nav" to your ul

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
```

Then add this script

```
 $(function() {
    $('#nav li a').click(function() {
       $('#nav li').removeClass();
       $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');
    });
 });
```